# Why do the API calls not work in Gremlin Python?

Tags: tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

In gremlin-python I can do:

```
for e in g.E().toList():
        print(e)
```

and will get a result like

```
e[11][4-created->3]
e[12][6-created->3]
e[7][1-knows->2]
e[8][1-knows->4]
e[9][1-created->3]
e[10][4-created->5]
```

According to

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.4.3/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Edge.html

an Edge has a inVertex() accessor.
Translating this idea to python leads to:

```
for e in g.E().toList():
        print (e.inVertex().id)
```

and the error

```
AttributeError: 'Edge' object has no attribute 'inVertex'
```

the same holds true for quite a few other "simple" API calls.

```
for e in g.E().toList():
        print(e.property('weight'))
```

also fails

**What is this so and what is the workaround?**

Answer (score 3):

In TinkerPop graph elements (e.g. vertices, edges, vertex properties) often go through a process of "detachment". Gremlin traversals that return graph elements from remote sources go through this process and, in these cases, are typically detached to "references". A reference provides just enough information to re-attach to the remote graph. For that process of re-attachment it only needs `id` and `label`. Therefore, properties are not returned. It is the same for all languages that Gremlin supports, not just Python (though, I will contradict this statement a bit at the end in a final note).

Speaking specifically for Gremlin Language Variants, like Python, these implementations of Gremlin do not have a full Gremlin Virtual Machine to process traversals and it was never an intent to build full graph structures on the Python side - only graph elements with references to match what would be returned from remote sources. That also reduces the amount of code on the Python side that needs to be maintained because TinkerPop can rely on standard primitives like `Dictionary`, `List` etc. that exist in all programming languages.

Technical history aside, the return of references forces uses to write better Gremlin according to best practices. Users should specify exactly what data they want in their Gremlin traversal. Rather than:

```
g.V().hasLabel('customer')
```

you would prefer:

```
g.V().hasLabel('customer').valueMap(true,'name')
```

or in 3.4.4:

```
 g.V().hasLabel('customer').elementMap('name')
```

which returns a less nested structure than `valueMap()`. `elementMap()` works very nicely for edges and is a replacement for more complex approaches via `project()` to get the data you're requesting from an edge in your question:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').elementMap()
==>[id:1,label:person,name:marko,age:29]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').elementMap('name')
==>[id:1,label:person,name:marko]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').properties('name').elementMap()
==>[id:0,key:name,value:marko]
gremlin> g.E(11).elementMap()
==>[id:11,label:created,IN:[id:3,label:software],OUT:[id:4,label:person],weight:0.4]
```

It's really no different in SQL where you likely wouldn't do:

```
SELECT * FROM customer
```

but instead:

```
SELECT name FROM customer
```

Returning references and forcing users to be a bit more explicit about what they return also solves a massive problem with multi/meta-properties. If a user returns vertices and inadvertently returns a "fat" vertex (e.g. a vertex with 1 million properties on it), it will have a significant impact to the server in trying to return that. By detaching to reference, there is no loophole for users to get stuck in.

All that said, as of 3.4.3, there are points of inconsistency with detachment still and in some cases in Java there are other ways that detachment works beyond reference detachment. TinkerPop has been trying to become completely consistent in this approach but have been trying to do it in a fashion that does not break existing code within existing release lines. This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but at least it helps explain some of the reasoning and history for why things are as they are.

Answer (score 1):

`toList()` execute the gremlin query and packs the result in a list.
Thus, you cannot continue the traversal with `inVertex()`.

To get the entering vertices you should run:

```
for v in g.E().inV().toList():
        print(v)
```

To get the edge properties and both vertices properties in a single query, you can use `project`:

```
g.E().project("values", "in", "out")
    .by(valueMap(true))
    .by(inV().valueMap(true))
    .by(outV().valueMap(true))
```

Comment: Thank you for this proposal. And then I'd have to to this for outV() a second time and do a third request for the properties ...

Comment: I updated the answer, now that I understand your request. I thought your question was about the error.

Comment: thank you for the improvement. Your code is not valid python.  The multiline statement is problematic. true needs to be "True" and valueMap is not defined. Also the imports are missing. I'd love to put this in my tutorial but I failed trying.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code at https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/structure/graph.py (see below) the following properties are directly accessible:

for all elements:

```
e.id
e.label
```

for edges:

```
e.inV
e.outV
```

The bad news is that properties need first be retrieved so it is not so easy to access ids, labels and properties in a single python statement.

```py
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, id, label):
        self.id = id
        self.label = label

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.id == other.id

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)


class Vertex(Element):
    def __init__(self, id, label="vertex"):
        Element.__init__(self, id, label)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "v[" + str(self.id) + "]"


class Edge(Element):
    def __init__(self, id, outV, label, inV):
        Element.__init__(self, id, label)
        self.outV = outV
        self.inV = inV

    def __repr__(self):
        return "e[" + str(self.id) + "][" + str(self.outV.id) + "-" + self.label + "->" + str(self.inV.id) + "]"
```